# PHP mail(): Two servers and SPF

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I have the following setup:

Server 1 (client-server):

- Running at `111.111.111.111`
- Hosting `myawesomedomain.com` with
  email server.
- Includes TXT DNS: `"V=SPF1 A MX INCLUDE:MYAWESOMEDOMAIN.COM ip4: 222.222.222.222/32 ?ALL"`

Server 2 (one of my machines):

- Hostname: `warning.othercorp.net`
- Running at `222.222.222.222`.

I want to use the server 2, via PHP `mail()`function to send email email warning to registered users in a back office.

I tried to send mail with a simple PHP script like the following but it gets marked as SPAM in Oulook.com and GMAIL says it was sent via `warning.othercorp.net`

```
$to = "someone@outloook.com";
$subject = 'Warning!';
$message = 'hello! You\'ve been warned!';
$headers = 'From: warning@myawesomedomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: info@myawesomedomain.com' . "\r\n";

$res = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
var_dump($res);
```

I'm not an expert in email sending, but what can I do to avoid emails marked as spam? Wasn't the SPF entry with the IP of the server 2 enough? Why?

---

Edit:

I was doing some tests, and after viewing the source of a test email sent to an @gmail address, I got this:

```
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 222.222.222.222 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for the domain of warning@myawesomedomain.com) client-ip=222.222.222.222;
```

I guess Outlook is flagging the email as spam because it has the same problem of GMAIL, what should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: The TTL was set to 86400. It was updated almost 48h ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send mail from `myawesomedomain.com`, I think the `TXT` record for `myawesomedomain.com` should be:

```
"v=spf1 a mx ip4:222.222.222.222 ?all"
```

Provided that:

- the `A` record for `myawesomedomain.com` is your `111.111.111.111` address
- your MX records are pointing to machines that actually send mail for the domain (as opposed to just receiving).

I suspect your `/32` CIDR notation is causing the issue with the second server.

Comment: `openspf.org` recommends using CIDR, but they also say it works without it. Is there a way I can debug this without changing the DNS on the first server? I need to ask the client to do it..

Comment: I don't know of any way to debug it, sorry. This sort of thing is such a pain. Usually when I am testing something like this I drop the record's TTL very low while I am adjusting and testing. Sucks when you have to ask the client to do  it, though.

Comment: Hey, please check my last edit. I also asked the client to remove the CIDR as you told me, but I'm still waiting on the change!

Comment: Based on my experience, the exact TXT record I gave should suffice to fix the issue in the quoted header you show. I'm not able to offer much else on it. Sorry. If you send me the domain I can query the server to see what it responds with.

Comment: I managed to get half of the problem (Gmail) solved setting the `Sender` and `From` email headers, to different values, where `Sender` is my client's email and `From` a local account on the server I'm using to send email. It's also important to set a `Return-path` (same as local server) and a `Reply-to` address.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrectly placed or double spaces in an SPF record can invalidate the record.

The record you've shared is:

> `V=SPF1 A MX INCLUDE:MYAWESOMEDOMAIN.COM ip4: 222.222.222.222/32 ?ALL`

There should be no space between `ip4:` and `222.222.222.222`

That might help solve the remaining issue for you.